# DXE compiler error. No table 'row' found in DXE. Source name: DxeAPI. XML: None in OBIEE direct sql request

Tags: obiee, oracle-bi

When I'm trying to run a direct sql Analysis which I built using direct SQL request. I get the following error message:

Error
    View Display Error

DXE compiler error. No table 'row' found in DXE. Source name: DxeAPI. XML: None
  Error Details
Error Codes: YV3KVTDM
Refresh

I'm able to validate the sql and it shows me the column I've selected in 'criteria' tab but shows me the above error in the result tab.

Comment: Needs more infornation. What's your source? What's your query? You are completely bypassing the core of OBI so it all depends on your query and your source connection.

Comment: @Chris this seemed like a random error, did get through with this one in a couple hours